# maximum number of edges given shortest distance between two nodes

Tags: graph-theory, extremal-graph-theory

In directed a graph with n nodes, we know that the distance between a specific vertex $s$ and a specific vertex $t$ is $k$.
What's the maximum number of edges this graph can have?

My attempt: reasoning on the path: s -> 2 -> .. -> k -> t

Since we couldn't skip from s to 3 or 4 or .. or t. the edges $\mid \{ (s,3),  .., (s,k), (s,t)\}\mid = k-1 $, do not exist. And the same starting from 2 for a path of length $(k-1)$ and so on. In total at least $\sum_{i=2}^k (i -1) = \frac{k\cdot (k-1)}{2}$ edges are missing.

Edit: Thanks to @Steven's comment we can also exclude $n - (k +1)$ edges if $k > 2$. One for each vertex not on the path.

Comment: Keep in mind that for all subsets $S$ of the remaining vertices (not on the path) with $|S|<k-1$, at least one edge must be missing between vertices of $S\cup s \cup t$, since we would otherwise have a shorter path.

Comment: that's true, thanks. but I don't know how to incorporate that without overcounting. The same edge can exclude multiple subsets.

Comment: I didn't know how to get a 'tight' bound either, but for example for $S$ a singleton $\{x\}$, we would always have distinct edges $[s,x]$ and $[x,t]$. So I think it is safe to conclude that  at least half of the edges of this type must be excluded as well (unless $k\leq2$ of course).